# How can I programmatically get a list of orders purchased by a specific user?

Tags: 8, commerce

how can i get list of commerce order purchased by specific user programatically?

i want to create function for it so that other developers can use it in further development by simply calling that function.
i want to get name of orders purchased by user based on uid.

i have used drupal commerce module for it,i am not getting any table column in database where i can get relevant data.

Answer (score 2):

to get ALL orders of a user - get user ID ($user_id)
then

```
$orders = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('commerce_order')
  ->loadByProperties(['uid' => $user_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 has view called **"User Orders"** with contextual filters already configured

So you can get that view results with this line of code.

```
$orders = views_get_view_result('commerce_user_orders', 'order_page', $uid);
```